# Handling transaction context using method attribute in linq to sql

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, isolation, atomic

Is there a way to just put an attribute to a method so that the whole code in the method is executed in a transaction scope? I've seen this done in sharp architecture but I'm using Linq to sql not nhibernate. Thanks!

This what I would like to do:

```
[Transaction] 
public void InsertCustomer(Customer customer)
{ //insert customer }
```

So that the body of the method executes in a transaction scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method? If you mean `SubmitChanges`, then I *believe* that is already transactional. Otherwise, just spin up your own `TransactionScope` around what you want controlled, or pass in a configured connection to the `DataContext` overloaded constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I updated my post to show you what I would like to do.

Comment: @ryudice - not AFAIK, but the insert itself (via `SubmitChanged`) should *already* be transactional (run a trace).